# Implementation of Dicky-Fuller test in R

Tags: r

I'm working with Dicky-Fuller test.

The steps are as follows:

1. Starting with model 3, test the significance of time trend. If it isn't significant, then go to step 2. If it is, then test the stationary of model 3.
2. Run model 2 (test the significant of drift, or constant). If it isn't significant, then go to step 3. If it is, then test the stationary of model 2.
3. Run model 1 (test the stationary)

However, my code doesn't run correctly. What mistakes did I make?

[image: Description of each model here]

```
data("PepperPrice")
Trend1=ur.df(PepperPrice[,"white"],type="trend",lags=0)
Trend2=ur.df(PepperPrice[,"white"],type="drift",lags=0)
Trend3=ur.df(PepperPrice[,"white"],type="none",lags=0)
summa1=summary(Trend1)
summa2=summary(Trend2)
summa3=summary(Trend3)

if summa1@teststat[,"phi3"] < summa1@cval["phi3","5pct"] {
    if summa2@teststat[,"phi1"]<summa2@cval["phi1","5pct"] {
        if summa3@teststat < summa3@cval["tau1","5pct"] {
          "stationnaire"
          } else {
            "non stationnaire"
          }
    } else {
      if summa2@teststat[,"tau2"] < summa2@cval["tau2","5pct"] {
        "stationnaire"
      } else {
        "non stationnaire"
      }
    }
} else {
  if summa1@teststat[,"tau3"] < summa1@cval["tau3","5pct"] {
    "stationnaire"
  } else {
    "non stationnaire"
  }
}
```

Comment: Stats methods questions are on-topic at crossvalidated.com